# Issues with sending mail via php

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-mail, mailing

In our site whole business model depends on email exchange. We are using `zend_mail` for send email / notification to our customers.

We are facing some issues with email delivery, listed below -

1. Sometimes it stops sending email to anyone and starts working automatically
2. Not sending emails on hotmail , live accounts
3. Emails going to spam folder for some  of customers email

What additional configuration required for email handling ? How the popular sites do this for sending bulk notifications , emails ? We have dedicated server and can do any configuration on server(linux).

Please let me know how to solve this issue.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I'm using Zend_Mail library and feel everything seems ok.
I think it depends on the content of your email.

Answer (score 0):

You might be better looking at swiftmailer or other mail library. They add additional headers and formatting to comply with email standards.

Comment: thanks. But I don't think so. Zend_mail itself is a good library. What is your view about this ?

Comment: It's good but needs extending to support inline images etc. Not had any trouble myself but we use an external mail server (webhost company) to deliver the mail. Use Zend_Mail to create the email and send via smtp through mail server.

Comment: I'm currently re-building our sytem using zf1.12 (stuck with PHP 5.3 for the time being) and torn between building a mail quing sytem or using an external service with good API like mail chimp.

Comment: How can I do this. Can you please elaborate ?